# WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectingToIdentityProvider event is not called

Tags: asp.net, wif

I have 2 events in my Global.asax.cs file

**WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenValidated** and **WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider**

WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider is not called by wif engine. Why?

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{ 
    void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenValidated(object sender, SecurityTokenValidatedEventArgs e)
    {
        FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.IsSessionMode = true;
    }


    void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider(object sender, RedirectingToIdentityProviderEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

This is microsoft.identityModel section in web.config

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
        <service saveBootstrapTokens="true">
          <audienceUris mode="Never">

          </audienceUris>
          <federatedAuthentication>
            <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://localhost/dss.web.sts.tokenbaker/" realm="http://localhost/dss.web.frontend" requireHttps="false" />
            <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />



          </federatedAuthentication>

          <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <trustedIssuers>
              <add thumbprint="308efdee6453fff68c402e5eceee5b8bb9eaa619" name="servcert" />

            </trustedIssuers>
          </issuerNameRegistry>
        </service>
      </microsoft.identityModel>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the passiveRedirectEnabled attribute is set to true on the <federatedAuthentication> element in your web.config?

Comment: Can you post the microsoft.identityModel section of your web.config?  That should help diagnose the situation.

Comment: I added content of microsoft.identityModel section

Comment: I was surprised to see that the methods get called automatic in my application today. I always registered them on the events. You can find events for them also: FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated +=FederatedAuthentication_FederationConfigurationCreated;

Answer (score 8):

You are missing following lines in your web.config:

In configSections element:

```
<section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

In system.webServer element

```
 <modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

Your audience Uris is empty. You have to specify your web application, so it can consume this functionality. So, add this line :

```
  <audienceUris>
    <add value="http://localhost/dss.web.frontend"/>
  </audienceUris>
```

If your problems reamined after this changes, you can implement your custom authentication module derived from WSFederationAuthenticationModule. Something like this :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationModule : WSFederationAuthenticationModule
{
    public CustomAuthenticationModule()
    {
        base.SecurityTokenReceived += CustomAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenReceived;
    }

    public void CustomAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnAuthenticateRequest(sender, args);
    }
}
```

and then just in config change instead of WSFederationAuthenticationModule put CustomAuthenticationModule  with appropriate namespace and assembly signature. So you can intercept calls in your delegate.

Hope this is helpful for you.

Rastko

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your Global.asax.cs:

```
void Application_Start()
{
    FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += OnServiceConfigurationCreated;
}


void OnServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectingToIdentityProvider += WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider;
}
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9207505/13932

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're referencing `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` from the new namespace`System.IdentityModel.Services`.

In my case I was still referencing it from the old `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web` namespace after migrating the solution to .NET 4.5.

Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950590).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be missing the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` in your configuration.  Make sure you have this in `system.webServer\modules`:

```
<add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

And this in `system.web\httpModules`:

```
<add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638734.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is that you are referencing a consistent assembly between your web.config module and your Global.asax.cs `using` statement.  Since the type `RedirectingToIdentityProviderEventArgs` exists in both `System.IdentityModel.Services` and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web` (as of .NET 4.5) you might be adding the module from one assembly in web.config but referencing the event arg from the other assembly in Global.asax.cs.  I think that would fail.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had the following modules added to both the system.web/httpModules and system.webServer/modules sections.

```
  <add name="WsFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

Removing the elements from the system.web/httpModules section solved the issue and all events attached to the WSFederationAuthenticationModule instance were being fired.

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are sub-classing `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` and therefor changing the module registration name in the `web.config` and are using the auto wiring approach (inside the `global.asax.cs`) you will also have need to change the beginning of the method name.

For example if you have the following in `system.webServer\modules`

```
<add name="CustomWsFedModule" type="SomeLib.CustomWSFederationAuthenticationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

You will need the following inside your `global.asax.cs`

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{ 
    void CustomWsFedModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider(object sender, RedirectingToIdentityProviderEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```