# FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule is null at runtime

Tags: asp.net, wif

I am trying to subcribe to **RedirectingToIdentityProvider** event in **Application_Start()** , but        FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule is null

code

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
 FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectingToIdentityProvider += WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider;
}
```

Comment: Same issue, have done as @garrett suggested with no results.

Comment: Did anyone get an answer on this?

Answer (score 6):

Try doing this - works for me.

```
void Application_Start()
{
    FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += OnServiceConfigurationCreated;
}


void OnServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectingToIdentityProvider += WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider;
}
```

Comment: I think `.ServiceConfigurationCreated` is not present in `System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication` (the .NET 4.5 implemenation.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a precision for .net 4.0

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
          <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
....
<system.webServer>    
    <modules>      
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />      
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may be missing the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` in your configuration.  Make sure you have this in `system.webServer\modules`:

```
<add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

And this in `system.web\httpModules`:

```
<add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638734.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Can I add it in runtime instead of web config?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure in your Global.asax you referencing the

```
System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule
```

and not:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule
```

The wrong (inconsistent between web.config and global.asax) reference will cause the WSFederationAuthenticationModule be null.