# Why would FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule be null in MVC Azure ACS Federated Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, .net-4.5, federated-identity

I'm trying to put together FederatedAuthentication with .NET 4.5, MVC 4, and active redirect using a custom server-side login page, using code from [this](http://garvincasimir.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/tutorial-mvc-application-using-azure-acs-and-forms-authentication-part-2/) tutorial, and from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh127794.aspx) code sample.

Redirecting to the LogOn method of my AccountController works fine, and the method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    HrdClient hrdClient = new HrdClient();
    WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule; /*** Fails here because this is null **/
    HrdRequest request = new HrdRequest(fam.Issuer, fam.Realm, context: Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    IEnumerable<HrdIdentityProvider> hrdIdentityProviders = hrdClient.GetHrdResponse(request);
    ViewData["Providers"] = hrdIdentityProviders;
    return View();
}
```

This fails because `FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule` is null.

Using VS 2012, I've run the new Identity and Access wizard (which seems to replace the old STS dialog). This has given me a folder of FederationMetadata, which appears correct, and several modifications to my Web.Config. In particular, the modules section looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

And having seen SO answers [8937123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937123/federatedauthentication-wsfederationauthenticationmodule-is-null-at-runtime) and [8926099](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926099/wsfederationauthenticationmodule-redirectingtoidentityprovider-event-is-not-call), I've added the following as well:

```
 <httpModules>
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</httpModules>
```

And finally my nuget packages config shows Microsoft.IdentityModel, which is correctly referenced by the MVC app:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel" version="6.1.7600.16394" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I've also seen [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuresecurity/thread/ba44f757-945c-4622-9b2d-feb9a56fe71e) on social.msdn, which just seems to suggest that the STS dialog does need to be run.

Can anybody explain why `FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule` would be null, and what I can do to stop this happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself, and since there are a few unanswered questions similar to this on SO, I'll leave the question up and post my own answer.

The issue is to do with upgrading the MVC application to .NET 4.5. Much of the WIF functionality remains the same (at least on the surface), but the classes have all moved to different assemblies. I fixed my problem following the migration guidelines here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157089.aspx

The most important thing is to remove old references to the `Microsoft.IdentityModel` package (v 3.5.0) and make sure they are replaced by similar references to the `System.IdentityModel` and `System.IdentityModel.Services` dlls, which should be version 4.0, and come from the GAC rather than an external package.

My steps to fix were:

- Clean out all the junk I'd added to Web.Config and start again with a default MVC Config file.
- Remove the `Microsoft.IdentityModel` package and de-reference the dll
- Run the Access and Identity wizard in VS 2012
- Duplicate the `System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule` reference from `<system.webServer><modules>` in `<system.web><httpModules>`
- Add `<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" /></authentication>`
- Compile, test, dance little jig of delight...

And this got the original WIF3.5 / MVC3 [Code Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh127794.aspx) working under.NET 4.5

Comment: Wow, even with a brand-new MVC 4.5 application I somehow ended up with a reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel. And also needed to duplicate the module reference from <system.webserver> to <system.web>

Comment: Also, thank you for posting the answer!! Searching around the web for how things work in VS2012 / 4.5 for WIF right now is not straightforward at all.

Comment: Any chance you still have the web.config used and could paste it in?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan No, sorry. We refactored to .NET Core a while ago and although I imagine that file is in a backup somewhere, after this amount of time I wouldn't know where.